# How to make a cell customizable height for different lengths of information in REACT NATIVE?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a cell customizable height so that if one view has more information it will create an extra row, decrease the font size, and lengthen the height of the cell.

For example, like in Facebook comments, if someone posts a longer comment the cell height will increase automatically to fit all the comments in. I'm fairly new to React Native and had no luck finding anything like this online so if you guys can help me out it would be much appreciated! Thanks guys

Comment: this will happen naturally because react native uses flexbox

Comment: it doesnt happen naturally because I'm using a listview with fixed height for each row for now. What is an appropriate algorithm to use for height?

Comment: don't use a fixed height and the container should grow as needed

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, React Native implements flexbox, and the height of the view should adjust *as long as there is not height defined with either a height property or a defined flex size*.

As far as implementing a dynamic font size, as mentioned above, you could use a function that checks for the size of the string and returns a value based on the length:

```
_adjustFontSize(string){
  if(string.length > 30) {
      return 14
  } else {
      return 30
  }
}
```

And implement it like so, which can be used in a listview or map / loop, passing in the data being looped through:

```
<Text style={{fontSize: this._adjustFontSize(data)}}>{data}</Text>
```

[Here](https://rnplay.org/apps/MbZ6tA) is a project implementing everything discussed here: https://rnplay.org/apps/MbZ6tA